# WooCommerce Tabs

Tags: php, functions, plugins, tabs

In my theme, I have the *WooCommerce* plugin installed and would like to rename the "*Catalog*" tab, located under the *WooCommerce* > *Settings* submenu page.

Am I able to do this from my `functions.php` file so that I'm not directly modifying the plugin itself and if so, how?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, there's a filter for it: `woocommerce_settings_tabs_array`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_settings_tabs_array', 'wpse94969_settings_tabs_array' );
function wpse94969_settings_tabs_array($tabs){
    $tabs['catalog'] = __('Products','your_textdomain'); // or whatever you fancy
    return $tabs;
}
```

This will take care about the tab title itself:
[image: Woocommerce rename settings tab]

The word "Catalog" appears again in two field labels below though.
To change these you can take advantage of the `woocommerce_catalog_settings` filter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_settings', 'wpse94969_catalog_settings' );
function wpse94969_catalog_settings($fields){

    foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
        if ( 'catalog_options' == $field['id'] )
            $fields[$key]['title'] = __('Products Options','your_textdomain');
        if ( 'shop_catalog_image_size' == $field['id'] )
            $fields[$key]['title'] = __( 'Products Images', 'your_textdomain' );
    }
    return $fields;
}
```